# How Replace function in Pig works?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My input file name is words.txt as below . Also there  is no space in each record of this below file .

```
 Hi
 Hi
 How
```

I am loading this file into Pig

```
words = LOAD '/user/inputs/words.txt' USING PigStorage() AS (line:chararray);

words_each = FOREACH words GENERATE REPLACE(line,'','|') ;

dump words_each;
```

I am getting output as

```
 |H|i|
 |H|i|
 |H|o|w|
```

But I would like to know how exactly REPLACE functions treats '' which is my second argument in REPLACE function .

There is no empty space in my file, then how come I am getting | in my output .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, As per your statement, REPLACE function is called on `''`. It doesn't contain any whitespace.
If you want to replace the space, you need to give it like this `' '`.  +

Both are different conditions as given below:

```
words_each = FOREACH words GENERATE REPLACE(line,'','|') ; // without space
words_each = FOREACH words GENERATE REPLACE(line,' ','|') ; // with space
```

First condition will add the Pipe symbol(|) after each character, while 2nd condition won't make any impact because there is no space in your file content.

Comment: Thanks for your answer .